# jQuery — append(), then .click() + $(this).parent()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to add a click function to an appended html element? Additionally, is it possible to do something to the parent of that appended element? For example, add or remove a class of its immediate parent?

Here's some pseudo code:

// Jade

```
.container.test

  .content
    | Some content
```

// JS

```
$('.content').append('<button>Button</button>')

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent('.container').removeClass('test')
})
```

Comment: Can you specify what triggers the JS to execute and how the set of elements with class content would change?

Comment: There's actually another sibling element to .content, which is another button. When that's clicked the .content slides in like an off canvas menu. Since I'm appending another button within .content my plan is to target that and hide the .content element when you click on the appended button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
var $button = $('<button>').text('Button');
$('.content').append($button);

$button.on('click', function() {
  $button.parent('.container').removeClass('test')
})
```

This is why it's best practice to create HTML elements using jQuery (or another library of your choice) and then append/prepend/replace the element, instead of appending/prepending/replacing raw HTML strings.

Comment: Hmmm...It so simple now that I see it. This did the trick. Thanks @gladsocc

Comment: @gladsocc There seems to be an issue when I go this route and have multiple .container elements. Namely, if I have, say 3, instances of .container the script with append 3 $button elements per .container. Any idea how I could restrict it to only appending 1 $button instance per .container?

Comment: @Sat please see edit. `$button.parent` instead of `$(this).parent`

Comment: I see. Is there no way around not having to explicitly targeting each .container? For example, if the number of .container instances are dynamic?

Comment: @Sat: There is. Please see the edit. The edited code will only target the parent container of each button.

Comment: @Sat - If there are many, what metric do you have to target the specific one? @gladsocc - `.parent()` will always only examine the first parent element, placing a selector there only means that if the parent element doesn't match the selector then nothing happens.

Comment: @TravisJ I'm creating mini off canvas elements specifically for mobile views of a website. How the DOM elements are organized will strictly remain the same so that .parent() should alway work for each individual off canvas element.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like below:

```
$('.content').append($('<button>Button</button>').click(function() {
   $(this).parent('.container').removeClass('test');
}));
```

Another solution is to use event delegation (bind event on `document`).

```
$('.content').append('<button>Button</button>');

$(document).on('click', '.content button', function() {
  $(this).parent('.container').removeClass('test');
});
```

Comment: Event delegation is another cool approach. I'd do `$('.content').on('click', 'button'` however. Granularity results in better garbage collection and unbinding.